# Compute difference between consecutive elements in a given list of integers

Tags: haskell

I'm using `zipWith`. i get the correct results but with incorrect signs. How do I fix it? Where am I going wrong?

```
diff :: [Int] -> [Int]
diff [] = []
diff x = zipWith (-) (tail x) x
```

result:

```
diff  [4,2,7,3,6,5]
[-2,5,-4,3,-1]
```

I want:

```
[2,-5,4,-3,1]
```

Comment: `zipWith (-) x (tail x)`

Comment: @pdexter if you put it as an answer, I'll approve it

Comment: Note that you could simply write `diff x = zipWith (-) x (tail x)` without the base case of `[]`, because when `x` is empty `zipWith` wont evalute its second argument and thus `tail` wont trigger an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have it now you're calculating `[2-4,7-2,3-7,6-3,5-6]`. If you swap the order of your arguments to `zipWith (-) x (tail x)` then you will correct it to `[4-2,2-7,7-3,3-6,6-5]`

Comment: And, as a somewhat subtle side benefit, you will also stop crashing on `[]`.

Comment: You can also shorten it a little as `diff = (zipWith (-)) <*> tail` (point-free and no explicit base case necessary) (although far less readable until you get used to `<*>`).